# Как называются по-заумному такие люди?

Tags: терминология

Всех с Новым Годом!
Как называются по-заумному (термин) такие люди, которые в обычном общении с переизбытком применяют следующие (примерно приведено) фразы, дабы показать превосходство своего якобы умственного развития над вашим, а попросту унизить?

`"С точки зрения банальной эрудиции весь цинизм ваших помыслов в данной концепции равен парадоксальным иллюзиям"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Что-то не могу себе представить людей, употребляющих заумные слова в обычном разговоре. Видимо, самое близкое их название всё-таки, как сказал @behemothus, снобы. Снобизм — претензия на высокую интеллектуальность, изысканный вкус или авторитетность в какой-то области и при этом надменное отношение к тем, кто якобы лишён этих достоинств.

Есть ещё слово *резонёр* (книжн.) — человек, любящий вести пространные 
рассуждения, преимущественно нравоучительного характера.

Но такую фразу, как у Вас, произносят просто люди с юмором, которые хотят поставить на место "умника", несущего заумь. Это известный мем, гуляющий с советских времён.

Автором, вытянувшим эту фразу из анналов произведений Эммануила Канта, а в частности "Критики чистого разума", скорее всего был какой-то студент, готовившийся к экзамену по философии и случайно (ключевое слово "случайно") заостривший внимание на словосочетании "банальная эрудиция". А дальше, полный дикого восторга он переписал этот фрагмент мыслей Канта и всю ночь учил, чтобы  выдать утром ее на-гора.

А потом понеслось. Кто-то где-то недослушал или недопонял. И вольная трактовка пошла гулять по умам российской интеллигенции с народными дополнениями и обновлениями.

Сама методика построения фразы выглядит следующим образом: в начале предложения произносится словосочетание "с точки зрения банальной эрудиции", за которым строится сложносочинённое предложение, максимально напичканное академическими терминами. Желательно, чтобы предложение было посвящено какой-то одной теме и включало в себя идею, аргументацию идеи и вывод. Кроме того, конечная фраза должна быть фонетически безупречна — произноситься легко и не резать слух.

Пример.

> С точки зрения банальной эрудиции, любой индивидуум, критически
>   мотивирующий абстракцию, не может игнорировать критерии утопического
>   субъективизма.

Вариация на тему банальной эрудиции: «С точки зрения диалектико-материалистического детерминизма, не каждая индивидуальность в двухфакторной концепции может сигнификативно воспринимать коммуникативное отражение, в общем, если смотреть сверху, то снизу кажется, что сбоку ничего нет».

Смысл в том, что человек, это произносящий, хочет сказать какую-то банальщину, известную всем, но тем не менее с очень умным видом, надеясь, что такие простачки, как все вокруг него, ничего из этой фразы не поймут, рты откроют от удивления и сразу зауважают.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы назвал бы подобного человека "пижон" (человек, стремящийся чем-либо выделиться, склонный к пустой демонстративности).

Answer (score 2):

Краснобаи. Если их декоративное пустословие агрессивно (явно направлено против кого-то), можно назвать их "воинствующими К. или демагогами". Менее дипломатично - пустозвонами или пустомелями.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще-то такое поведение называется снобизмом, а его носитель - снобом. Но тут есть два момента. Во-первых, это значение переносное, исходно сноб - это просто тот, кто стремится следовать манерам высшего общества. А во-вторых, даже это переносное значение более широко по сравнению с описываемой вами ситуацией.

Но это, имхо, самое близкое из того, что пока представлено.

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл в английской вики (проект заставляет писать, а то мало символов было) - **фразёр.**

Comment: Нет американской википедии — есть английская только! ;)

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой: Я не уверен. "Φразёр" - русское слово и есть в русскоязычном Викисловаре, английского "phraser" в английскоязычных Википедии и Викисловаре я не нашёл (французское есть), а можна сказать, что всё Викимедиа американское.

Comment: А что такое Викимедиа?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой [Фонд Викимедиа](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B4_%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0) это фонд, который поддерживает инфраструктуру для работы Википедии и других проектов. Извените, что так поздно отвечаю. Я раньше не заметил вопроса.

Comment: Ничего страшного, бывает. ;)

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой, вы зачем американскую Wikipedia на английскую исправили. Зачем идти против фактов?
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: Википедию на английском (языке) естественно назвать "английской". Почему же именно американская?! Вы думаете, в ней только американцы создают и редактируют страницы? :)) Например, я редактирую, а я вовсе не американец.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой, странное суждение у вас - если вы будете управлять автомобилем Audi, то от этого он станет менее немецким? И если вы даже туда установите сами русские шины, натяните чехлы не кресла с  флагом РФ и даже переведёте интерфейс консоли - то всё равно она вряд ли станет русской машиной...
Я тоже вел рубрику своего города... Но получился конфликт с администрацией, которая обратилась к законодательству США, а на законодательство РФ, она клала большой и толстый болт.
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Обсуждение:Канск

Comment: Так обоснуйте тогда, почему вы Википедию считаете американской.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой - Фонд "Викимедиа" (США), правообладатель товарным знаком "Википедиа".
Давайте я даже ссылку вам дам, иначе вы не сможете найти корни такого мегапроекта, как "Википедиа" самостоятельно: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B4_%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0

Answer (score 0):

То, о чем идет речь, называется корпоративным чванством. Корпоративным - потому что в речи используются термины свойственные профессиональным сообществам, научным, в том числе. Чванство - потому что специальная терминология используется в общении с непосвященным  слушателем, намеренно, с целью демонстрации своего превосходства и унижения собеседника. По сути - хамская выходка, проявление хамства.
  Оценочный термин "корпоративное чванство" применим  в оценке персон реально являющимися носителями научных знаний и "так"" себя ведущими.
  Можно ли применить термин " корпоративное чванство" для оценки персон  "кривляющихся под ученых", не являющихся реальными носителями специальных знаний и навыков? Думаю, что нет, это было бы неточным. Специальный же термин для вербальной характеристики этой категории мне неизвестен. Случайный гость.

Comment: Чванство - да, возможно, хотя и не совсем точно. Но при чем тут "корпоративное"?

Answer (score 0):

Или же человек, любящий софизмы.

СОФИ́ЗМ — можно подразделить на: сложное рассуждение, иногда намеренно запутанное с целью показать умственное превосходство, и словесное ухищрение, вводящее в заблуждение.

Answer (score -1):

Зануда — вот как таких называют.